# Matplotlib/Seaborn: ValueError when annotating 2nd subplot (annotating 1st subplot was successful)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I created this figure with two subplots and wanted to annotate both subplots separately (see figure and code below)

[image]

```
    # Declare fig ax
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=[12,10], sharey=True)


    # Line plot for ax[0]
    sns.lineplot(x=['2020-01-01', '2020-01-31'], y=[32.7477, 49.6184], ax=ax[0], marker='o', markersize=10)

    # Add title for ax[0]
    ax[0].set(title='Figure 1', xlabel=None, ylabel="Index")
    ax[0].tick_params(axis = 'x', rotation = 45)

    # Annotation for ax[0]
    ax[0].text(0, 55, 52.53)
    ax[0].text(0.4, 45, "Some annotation here", horizontalalignment='center', size='medium', color='black')
    ax[0].text(1, 52, 49.62, horizontalalignment='center', size='medium', color='black')


    # Line plot for ax[1]
    sns.lineplot(x="date", y="ari", data=df_ari_jan, ax=ax[1],  marker='o', markersize=10)


    # Add title for ax[1]
    ax[1].set(title='Figure 2', xlabel=None, ylabel="Index")
    ax[1].set_xticks(df_ari_jan["date"].values)
    ax[1].tick_params(axis = 'x', rotation = 45)

    # Annotation for ax[1]
    ax[1].text(-1, 0, 52.53)
fig.tight_layout()
```

Annotating the first subplot was fine, but I kept getting this `ValueError: Image size of 15006958x630 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.` when trying to annotate the 2nd one.

`fig.tight_layout()` wouldn't work either `UserWarning: Tight layout not applied. The left and right margins cannot be made large enough to accommodate all axes decorations.`

Any idea as to why?

Comment: Can you post a sample of `df_ari_jan` so that we can ruin your code? :)

Comment: In the first subplot you plot strings. Hence, 0, 0.4, and 1 are within the range of categorcial enumeration. In the second subplot you plot dates, where `-1` is completely outside the data range.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Should I convert the dates into strings then? Or if not, what value should I use so that it's within the data range?

Comment: I don't know what you should do, but you could decide to place the text at positions of the dates you plot.

Comment: If the text is related to a date you could try something like `ax[1].text('2020-01-01', 55, "text")`.   To also have the first plot with dates as x-axis, you could try `sns.lineplot(x=pd.to_datetime(['2020-01-01', '2020-01-31']), ...`.

Comment: @JohanC I tried your first suggestion just now and got this error `ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: '2020-01-01'`

Comment: I just upgraded to the latest versions of matplotlib and pandas. Now you seem to need `ax[1].text(pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01'), 55, "text")`

Comment: @JohanC Thanks, now it works! I just also updated mine yesterday.